# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: tr#312:.14.16.44040312:.14.16.17.12.44

Tags: jquery

Buen dia, tengo la siguiente línea que me da el error: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: tr#312:.14.16.44040312:.14.16.17.12.44,` trate de usar stringfy, pero nada

```
$('tr#'+id[i]+'').css('background-color', '#ff0000');

id: 312:.14.16.44040312:.14.16.17.12.44
```

Comment: Utiliza el selector con id `$('tr [id="312:.14.16.44040312:.14.16.17.12.44"]')`

Comment: @Emerita da el mismo error

Comment: Utiliza sin el # se me paso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el selector por id, dentro del JQuery puedes utilizar la siguiente forma

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div[id="312:.14.16.44040312:.14.16.17.12.44"]').css('background-color', '#ff0000');
})
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="312:.14.16.44040312:.14.16.17.12.44" style="width:50px;height:50px">Valor</div>
```

Primero haces referencia al elemento en este caso un div luego seleccionas el id tal cual esta referenciado
    ***Elemento***
    `div` luego **id** `[id="312:.14.16.44040312:.14.16.17.12.44"]`

En tu caso para hacer que funcione debes concatenar lo faltante

```
$('tr[id="'+id[i]+'"]').css('background-color', '#ff0000');
```

Comment: $('tr[='+id[i]+']') asi?

Comment: Ahi edite la respuesta, para que te des una idea de como debe quedar

Comment: jquery parsea el selector, en este caso usa comillas, si queres usar el `#` hay que "escapear" los caracteres que tienen otro sentido para jquery ref1: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/  ref2: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ ref3: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-attrdef-global-id